# Variable contains period in perl, but I don't want to concat

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to create a hash from tabular data. One of the columns contain team names that are separated by .'s - for instance USA.APP.L2PES.

A sample line that will be split (| are delimiters):

```
http://10.x.x.x:8085/BINReport/servlet/Processing|2012/10/02 08:40:30|2015/03/10 16:00:42|nxcvapxxx_bin|Chandler|Linkpoint Connect|USA.APP.L2PES
```

And here is the code I'm using to split and arrange into a hash (found on another stack exchange comment).

```
my @records;
while (<$fh_OMDB>) {
    my @fields = split /\s*\|\s*/, $_;
    my %hash;
    @hash{@headers} = @fields;
    push @records, \%hash;
}
for my $record (@records) {
    my $var = $record->{Arg04};
    print $var;
}
```

However, whenever I try to print $var I get the error message

> Use of uninitialized value $var in print at find_teams_v2.pl line 53,
>    line 2667.

I believe this is because the string contains a . and perl is trying to concat the values. How do I print the string as a literal?

Here is an output of Data dumper (only one of them, as there are a couple thousand output):

```
$VAR1 = {
      'Arg01' => 'zionscatfdecs',
      'Date Added' => '2013/08/06 10:30:04',
      'URL' => 'https://zionscat.fdecs.com',
      'Arg04
' => 'USA.FDFI.APP.TMECS2
',
      'Date Updated' => '2013/08/06 10:30:04',
      'Arg02' => 'Omaha',
      'Arg03' => 'First Data eCustomer Service ()'
    };
```

And the headers dump:

```
$VAR1 = 'URL';
$VAR2 = 'Date Added';
$VAR3 = 'Date Updated';
$VAR4 = 'Arg01';
$VAR5 = 'Arg02';
$VAR6 = 'Arg03';
$VAR7 = 'Arg04
';
```

Comment: Are you initializing `@headers` anywhere?  Can you show us that code?

Comment: More likely `$record -> {Arg04]` is undefined, and that's getting plonked into `$var`. Try printing it with `Data::Dumper`

Comment: You may also find you can just split on `|` rather than needing that regex.

Comment: Headers is initialized earlier (its just the first line of the file, making an array using split and <$fh_OMDB>.

It appears that the value is defined - I've added a data dumper on one of the values to the main body

Comment: OK. Can you run `print Dumper \@headers` and edit that into your question?

Comment: The key has a newline in it. Use `chomp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking up my own `@headers` it seems to work ok.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @headers = qw ( mee mah mo mum
                   fee fi fo fum );

my $string =
    q{http://10.x.x.x:8085/BINReport/servlet/Processing|2012/10/02 08:40:30|2015/03/10 16:00:42|nxcvapxxx_bin|Chandler|Linkpoint Connect|USA.APP.L2PES};

my @records;
my @fields = split /\s*\|\s*/, $string;
print join( "\n", @fields );
my %hash;
@hash{@headers} = @fields;
print Dumper \%hash;
push @records, \%hash;

foreach my $record (@records) {
    my $var = $record ->{fo};
    print $var,"\n";
}
```

This prints the string - with the dots - as expected. That's because each loop the hash looks like (with your sample data):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fi' => 'Linkpoint Connect',
          'mo' => '2015/03/10 16:00:42',
          'mum' => 'nxcvapxxx_bin',
          'mee' => 'http://10.x.x.x:8085/BINReport/servlet/Processing',
          'mah' => '2012/10/02 08:40:30',
          'fee' => 'Chandler',
          'fum' => undef,
          'fo' => 'USA.APP.L2PES'
        };
```

However, if my 'headers' row is shorter:

```
my @headers = qw ( mee mah mo mum );
```

I can reproduce your error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $var in print
```

That's because there's no `{fo}` element:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'mo' => '2015/03/10 16:00:42',
          'mee' => 'http://10.x.x.x:8085/BINReport/servlet/Processing',
          'mum' => 'nxcvapxxx_bin',
          'mah' => '2012/10/02 08:40:30'
        };
```

So:

- Make sure you have `strict` and `warnings` switched on.
- check `@headers` is declared.
- check `@headers` is actually long enough to match every field.

Running:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@headers;
```

Will tell you this.

And as noted in the comments above:

```
      'Arg04
' => 'USA.FDFI.APP.TMECS2
```

`{Arg04}` doesn't exist, we have a newline. `chomp` your line before converting it into headers, (or just `chomp @headers`) and your code will work.

Note - you may also wish to `chomp` inside your while loop, because otherwise the last field will *also* include a newline. (Which may be undesired)

Comment: That helped Sobrique - combined with what ikegami said, I had an extra line on the headers. It looks like that was throwing it off. Would having an extra header give the same error as not having enough headers?

Comment: No. Too many headers won't cause a problem. As you can see in the above - I've got 8, and it just means the 8th 'column' is `undef`.

Comment: You may not need as complicated a split. For your sample data, `split ( '\|' );` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Data::Dumper` printouts showed that I had fewer header fields than existed, so that when I made the call to `Arg04` it didn’t exist or made a reference to an `undef` field. Doing a `chomp` on the header array fixed the error message.

Comment: You may wish to `chomp` the lines within the loop too, for much the same reason.

Comment: Also - well done for including your answer. It's good to see this sort of feedback loop. (It may have to wait until tomorrow before I can upvote it though)